# is it possible to purchase a product using curl php library and paypal?

Tags: php, curl, paypal

i have a client that provide a service on his website.he wants to automate the service orders.

the service has these steps:
1- user submit a form with request.
2- my client review the request, validate it and use the info in this request to :
3- login to another website
4- buy a product from this website using his paypal account.
5- downlad and send the product in email to the user.

i was able to automate all of this using curl.the only problem i have is the purchase process using papal.i didn't deal with paypal before.so i want to know if i can just submit the papal form on the purchase website using curl.or this will not work?

while searching i found something about papal IPN.but i don't know if my client have this IPN in his papal account or not? also, he does not want to give me his papal info. is there is anyway i can do this with fake paypal account to try it?

thank you so much.

Comment: I believe You can do this. But I don't think you should do this. This is pretty wired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, sign up for a PayPal sandbox account: https://developer.paypal.com/devscr?cmd=_signup-run

It's a really slick system PayPal put together for developers to test out stuff.

Secondly, review the PayPal API's at:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks

I believe all you need is the PHP Name-Value pair or Website Payments Standard interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

IPN stands for Instant Payment Notification, it's a way for PayPal to tell you that a payment *was* made.

What you are looking for is either the [PayPal NVP](http://www.google.com/search?q=PayPal%20NVP) or [SOAP](http://www.google.com/search?q=PayPal%20SOAP) interfaces.